# How to make Search method with EntityManager in DAO?

Tags: java, ejb, dao

I'm working on session bean (EJB3.0) and I need to make search method (in tables) for client.

I have 2 tables (TB1, TB2) with some columns (id, col2, col3)

For search I'm using such construct:

```
public TB1 findTB1( TB1 tb1 ) throws Exception{
    if (tb1.getId() == null ){
        _entityManager.persist(tb1);
         }
         else{


            return (tb1);
         }
    }
}
```

Is it right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doesn't quite work.

Firstly, I'd think about the persist part. When using find method I do not usually expect my entity to get persisted into DB.

Secondly, returning the object you have might not work (probably will not). That's because you have no guarantee that tb1, even if it's id is filled, is a managed bean at the moment. Also, I would expect `find` method to give me up-to-date row from DB and not the argument I passed.

The correct way is simply using the `find` method:

```
return _entityManager.find(TB1.class, tb1.getId());
```

And handling the case with id==null on a higher level. When you may not have a primary key to search with you do not search.